# Passing millisecond within Datetime in Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I would like to pass a `datetime` in the `querystring` but it has to carry the milliseconds.

When I attempt to do so, it only carries up to the second with PM or AM.

i.e -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { TGuid = item.TGuid, TDate = item.TDate })

TDate = {2/2/2017 4:33:32 PM}
```

But Millisecond property: 350

However, Details when accepting the datetime paramter, suddenly has lost the milliseconds:

```
public ActionResult Details(string TGuid, DateTime TDate)


TDate = {2/2/2017 4:33:32 PM}
```

Now, Milliseconds is 0.

How should I pass TDate making sure Millseconds is also captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried applying a format to the date time object? I'm sure by default the framework applies a tostring without parameters and it removes the miliseconds.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { TGuid = item.TGuid, TDate = item.TDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt") })
```

For more reference about datetime format check this out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882581(v=vs.110).aspx)